# Changes to the layout of item at position 0 of the gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a `gridview` which I am inflating with a `relativelayout`. Consider this as an example of the layout:

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
......
......
```

I have a `progress bar` in the layout, that I want to apply only to the layout at position 0. And update it using an `async task` after the adapter is set. Ofcourse with gridview I cannot just access view at position 0 and show/hide `progressbar` whenever it gets rendered again. What should I do in order to fix the layout of the first child of the gridview and do not let it change whenever the user scrolls through the items?

This is my method of `getView()`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_tvguide, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.showTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ShowTitle);
            holder.showDuration = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ShowTime);
                    //by default visibility is set to GONE
            holder.progBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            //logic to control the progressbar from asynctask
        if (this.updateNowPlaying){
            holder.progBar.setProgress(this.progress);
            return convertView;
        }

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                this.shows.get(position).getShowThumb(), holder.image);
        holder.showTitle.setText(this.shows.get(position).getShowTitle());
        holder.showDuration.setText(this.shows.get(position).getShowTime());

        return convertView;
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageHover"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/tile_selector_style" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ShowTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:hint="Show Title"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ShowTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:hint="Show Time"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my `gridview`:

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:columnWidth="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
        </GridView>
```

Comment: How will I do that without disturbing the layout? I am adding my `layout inflator` code as well.

Comment: @MikeM. I have tried your possible solution. It works fine, but now the issue is that this item is not the part of `gridview` anymore. Thats means no `scrolling`.

Comment: I want position 0 of the `gridview` to be a layout which contains `progressbar` in it. REST of the items in the `gridview` should `NOT` have a `progressbar` in them, no matter how much I scroll...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show the progress bar only for `item 0` add this code after `if/else` initializing your holder :

```
if (position == 0) {
    holder.progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thats what this code will produce. Upper left item will have a `ProgressBar`, which will be scrolled out properly and shown again when user scrolls back to `item 0`. What is your concern ?

Comment: @MikeM. yes. I want the `progressbar` to be visible on the upper left item ONLY. The whole `gridview` will consists of only 1 items with a `progressbar`

Comment: sorry, I can't visualize this behavior. So, when the user scrolls the `GridView`, lets say upper left item is partially scrolled out of screen. Does it show the progress ? Or the one below it ?

Comment: My apologies, kiruwka. It appears I was misunderstanding the OP.

Comment: @kiruwka In the whole `gridview`, the upper left item should contain a `progressbar`. Right now if I scroll, the new item that replaces item at position 0, also has a `progressbar`, and so on..

Comment: @faizanjehangir, are you sure you have kiruwka's code block _after_ the `if-else` in your code?

Comment: @MikeM. the above code works fine until I scroll down to a new row and item at `position 0` is replaced by a new item which now has a `progressbar` as well. I do not want that to happen..

Comment: Do you have it before or after the `if (this.updateNowPlaying)` block?

Comment: @faizanjehangir You wrote "the above code works fine until I scroll down to a new row and item at position 0 is replaced " - are you sure you copied the code I provided exactly as is ? What you describe should not happen, as progress bar is only enabled for pos == 0 and disabled (view.GONE) for the rest positions. And when you scroll down you will NOT have position 0 on screen, position is absolute to the `WHOLE gridView` and not to what you see on screen.

Comment: @kiruwka, I'm thinking he had your code after his last if-block, and it was returning before setting the ProgressBar to gone.

Comment: @MikeM. Good point. Let's clarify with OP again. This code should work given that behavior is what he wants( scrolling progress bar at pos 0 out/and back).

Comment: Yeah, I think you're absolutely right. That's what he's going for. I was misunderstanding him, and just made everything unduly confusing. Again, my apologies.

Comment: @MikeM. no worries. Hopefully we'll be able to help him eventually.

Comment: @MikeM.. I eventually happen to try out what you asked for.. Turned out the sequence of instructions was a problem here. Thank you for setting it right!